# What does "Endcode #816" stand for in Canon iR-ADV C5035 printer logs?

Tags: printer

We are using the Canon iR-ADV C5035. Today a worker has reported that *some* Word documents cannot be printed via that device (others do).

I could confirm that and found that the Canon iR-ADV C5035 logs showed an "Endcode" "#816" for every print job that was not printed (whereas other print jobs show an "Encode" "OK").

Unfortunately, neither the manual that came with the Canon copy machine nor the web seems to know what this "Endcode" means. Canon support has been informed, but I'm still waiting for them to call me back.

Does anyone know how I could find out what this "Endcode" stands for? Or, preferably, where I can look up the meaning of such Canon "Endcodes" in the future?

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Canon just called back. The error code means that the user in question has reached their print quota. Apparently, this used to be covered in older manuals, but is no longer.

Answer (score 0):

Change the setting in windows (settings/printers) from colour print into back-white print.
You may not be allowed to print in colour but only white black. That is why it was not working on my canon 3330i. Since I had colour page and this settings I got 816 error. After you change it, you will get a black-white page printed. Good luck

Comment: I wish he was able to print before this as it's a 7 years old question!